# Creating RTF and printing as PDF

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, printing

I'm trying to do the following(in this order):

1. Create a Rich Text Format file
2. Add company image to the top of page and write the data to the RTF
3. Print the RTF file as PDF through CutePDF or other printer that are 
   able to convert my RTF to a PDF and thereby save locally on the users PC - The pdf should be saved at a location without prompting the user
4. After this is done, the RTF file should be deleted and return a message, that confirms the action is successfully done.

Other stuff:

The website where these actions take place, are not meant to host the outcome(the PDFs) but these are supposed to be saved on the users PC. (is this possible without prompting the user to save it? i imagine the website would write directly to the users PC instead of doing the work on the website and save it and then transfer the file to the PC)

OBS: i do not wish to use any 3th party program/DLL other then the converter like cutePDF :)

My question is quite simple i hope :)

Will this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You can send the PDF back to the user but the user will either be prompted to download the file or it will open automatically (depending on the user's configuration and the response headers you're sending). Without using some sort of plugin you can't save any files directly to the user's computer.

If it was possible to write a file directly to the user's  the world as we know it would have ceased to exist.  Cities would lie in ruin as idle youtube commentators roamed the streets in violent gangs yelling "FIRST" and engaging in brutal and pointless gang wars. A generation of youth superbly trained by video games would manage to destroy civilization in a matter of days. Fortunately civilization would eventually be rebuilt by Minecraft players but it would take time.

If that functionality is really vital I would suggest looking at a plugin.

Comment: Even if i where choosing to "print" ? like with cutePDF? if the user had this installed could i print in that and somehow send the path as a parameter as to where to place the print file?

Comment: No. For security reasons the browser is a heavily sandboxed environment that doesn't allow you to interact with other programs on the user's computer that don't have hooks built into the browser to facilitate this. Saving a file to the user's computer without a plugin of some kind that would breach the firewall isn't possible (fortunately).

Comment: okay, so what if I'm to do it all in a HTML(i realized after a couple of hours sleep that i didn't need the RTF file) and by clicking a button (print) it will open a save/print-to-PDF dialog as to where to save it and the user then have to press OK/Save.
Is this possible? without the use of any plugin ( other  then cutePDF or similar)

Comment: You can use JavaScript to trigger the default print dialogue but the user will need to select "Print to PDF" (or whatever other option is available to them) as their printer and then save the file.

Comment: Do you have a link for a guide/tut on how to do that - my JavaScript skills are kinda rusty or non existing - ill give you a thumb up and mark this as an answer as you have my gratitude for helping me out here :P

Comment: Sure thing, check out this link: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3471121/Print-a-Web-Page-Using-JavaScript.htm